# Onchange in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, request

This is my  input type

```
->add(‘year’,  ChoiceType::CLASS, array(‘choices’ => $array, ‘attr’ =>  array(‘onchange’ => ‘this.form.submit()’)));
```

Onchange page is reloading and data is submitted. Then in controller I can access value like this:

```
$_POST[‘year’].
```

The thing is I would like to get $_POST in symfony’s way:

```
$form[‘year’]->getData();
```

I don’t know why only $_POST[‘year’] works and  no result  with $form[‘year’]->getData().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for **POST** request :

```
$request->request->get('year');
```

For **GET** request:

```
$request->query->get('year');
```

For **FILE** queries:

```
$request->files.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a single item from the form data like;

```
$year = $form->get('year')->getData();
```

In this example 'year' is the name given to the field you are asking for (as per your form builder)